# Catching JS errors on file include

Tags: javascript, include-path

is there any handler to catch an error when including / loading a js file?

I am looping through an array and appending a the scripts into my head.
is there any way I can see if the included JS file has an error ( ergo then I could get rid of the include sequence headaches, just looping through an array of js files that didnt load 5 or so times or evenby grabbing the files that gave errors, maybe handling  them, figuring out why they broke, then including them again)

```
var incFile=[
"Grid.EditGrid"
,"Data.AutoSaveStore"
,"Form.FormPanel"   
,"ux.Spotlight"
];


//http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml
//This can be extended to include css files aswell

//Dynamic Js file loading                               
loadJsFile = function(filename){
    var fileref=document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("src", "js"+filename);
    fileref.setAttribute("language","javascript");  
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);  
};


//The loop to include java files
for (var f=0;f<=incFile.length-1;f++){
var path = "";
var split = incFile[f].split(".");
//Build the relative path
for(var s=0;s<=split.length-1;s++){
    path +=  "/"+split[s];
};  
  loadJsFile(path+".js");
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onerror event on the document object, window object, or wire up the onerror event on the "fileref".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197053(v=vs.85).aspx

In your case you would just need to modify your code to the following:

```
fileref.setAttribute("language","javascript");      
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);  
fileref.onerror = myerrorhandler;

function myerrorhandler(){
   alert("error");
}
```